# How to remove "." from a filename in Perl?

Tags: command-line, perl

I do `/(\.[^.]+)$/` in Perl to read the extension of a file, for example `Text.txt`. How can I remove the `.` so that the output gonna be `Texttxt`?

Answer (score 2):

The match group `/(…)/` contains anything **inside** the parentheses. 
If you don't want the dot to be part of it, then put it **outside** 
the parentheses: `/\.([^.]+)$/`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'Test.txt';
$filename =~ s/(.*)\.([^.]+)$/$1$2/;
#               ^^    ^^^^^
#               $1     $2
print "filename: '$filename'\n";

# prints "Testtxt"
```